# Enabling 802.11w mode with hostapd

Tags: raspberry-pi, hostapd, wpa-supplicant

I'm trying to setup a WiFi Access Point with a Raspberry Pi 3B+ having 802.11w enabled.
Kernel version: Linux efb-ap-0 4.19.66-Re4son-v7+ #1 SMP Sun Aug 18 22:25:39 AEST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux
Driver: brcmfmac
hostapd (Deb package): 2:2.9-1 armel

During the 4-Way Handshake, wpa_supplicant immediatly disconnects at the 3/4 msg, with following logs:

> wlan0: WPA: IE in 3/4 msg does not match with IE in Beacon/ProbeResp (src=b8:27:eb:3b:3f:0e)
>   WPA: RSN IE in Beacon/ProbeResp - hexdump(len=28): 30 1a 01 00 00 0f ac 04 01 00 00 0f ac 04 01 00 00 0f ac 06 c0 00 00 00 00 0f ac 06
>   WPA: RSN IE in 3/4 msg - hexdump(len=26): 30 18 01 00 00 0f ac 04 01 00 00 0f ac 04 02 00 00 0f ac 02 00 0f ac 06 c0 00

Comparing 3/4 msg hexdump and Beacon hexdump via Wireshark shows that the Beacon contains the following additional fields that are not in the 3/4 msg: PMKID Count (0x00 00)+ PMKID List + Group Management Cipher Suite 
(0x00 0f ac 06).
Why is the 3/4 msg not matching the Beacon ? Is this an issue in hostapd ? in driver ? in hostapd<->driver communication ?

Thanks for any information about that.

You can find below the hostapd.conf content:

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
logger_syslog=-1
logger_syslog_level=2
auth_algs=1

wpa_pairwise=CCMP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
wpa=2

hw_mode=g
ieee80211w=2

ssid=XXXXXXXXXX
channel=1

wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK-SHA256
wpa_passphrase=XXXXXXXXXX
```

And the wpa_supplicant.conf used to connect:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/
network={
       ssid="XXXXXXXX"
       proto=RSN
       scan_ssid=1
       key_mgmt=WPA-PSK-SHA256
       pairwise=CCMP
       psk="XXXXXXXX"
       ieee80211w=2
       }
```

Note: this thread is a duplicate from a message I had posted on hostap mailing list for which I didn't have answer: http://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/hostap/2019-November/040764.html

Comment: This might be a driver/firmware issue of PI. For other WiFi adapters it seems to work, but not for the native WiFi adapter of PI.